# Is zlib useful to improve data transfer performance for BSD Scoket based client/server Application?

Tags: performance, zlib, tcp

I am working on a application which behaves both ways e.g client/server both, in a form of  network app installed on android/iphone.

network apps are linked with xmpp signaling, so peers can locate each other.

**Use case is :** a user can send files to remote peer or remote peers can send files to the user.

**Now my objective is to improve the data transfer performance**, and then I came to know about zLib  e.g. before sending the file it can be compressed and on receiving it can be decompresses that will improve the performance ?

**[1].** Is that feaisble to do ? (e.g. If files are larger than 5 MB or 2 MB or only on specific case ?)

**[2].** Is there any example to start with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the files?  If they are already compressed, e.g. jpg, mp3, mov, etc. then no, compression won't help.  You should simply try to compress your data with gzip or zip and see if it gets smaller.  That will give the first indication of whether zlib will help.

Second you need to consider the time taken to compress compared to the time saved by sending compressed instead of uncompressed data.

As for size, it doesn't matter.  zlib streams for both compression and decompression, so the entire file need never be stored by zlib.  You can feed it and be fed in chunks.

Comment: Most of the files types are :jpg, mp3, mov, and some of them are .doc,pdf,.txt , so it may help on some cases may be (any way I will perform the steps mentioned by you :-)

Comment: .doc and .txt will compress.  .pdf won't.  Nor will .docx.